# Delphi array index bounds

Tags: arrays, delphi

I wanted to see how delphi managed array and I have created this kind of code (using Delphi 10 Seattle and VCL):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var a: array[1..8] of integer;
    i: integer;
    res: string;
begin

try

 for i := 1 to 8 do
  a[i] := i*i;

 Memo1.Clear;
 res := '';

 for i := 1 to 8 do
  begin
   res := res + a[i].toString + ' ';
  end;

 Memo1.Lines.Add(res);

except
 on E: Exception do
  showmessage(E.Message);
end;

end;
```

I already know that I can use `Low()` and `High()` to safely select the lower and the upper bound. I had to make a program in which I couldn't use these 2 functions and I had to use integer variables (calculated somewhere else) instead.

I had found this weird behavior. The code above produces this output:

> 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64

When I try to change the bounds of both loops to 1 and 9 (for i := 1 to 9) I have this:

> 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81

Why is this not raising the exception? I have declared a as [1..8]. When I set the bounds to 1 and 10 (for i := 1 to 9) of both the exception is raised as I expect.

I also know `C++` and I know that there isn't a control on the array bound even if they are specified in the declaration, so a for loop can continue over the limit. Like I can have

```
int a[5] = {};

for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
 a[i] = i;
}
```

And this won't give me an error (basically because a[i] is the pointer *(a+i)). Are delphi arrays implemented with poineters as well but with a range check?

---

**EDIT**

Also when I use this code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var a: array[5..8] of integer;
    i: integer;
    res: string;
begin

try

 for i := 1 to 8 do
  a[i] := i*i;

 Memo1.Lines.Clear;
 res := '';

 for i := 1 to 8 do
  begin
   res := res + a[i].toString + ' ';
  end;

 Memo1.Lines.Add(res);

except
 on E: Exception do
  showmessage(E.Message);
end;

end;
```

I have the output below that looks incorrect to be because the bounds are 5..8 but I am doing a loop which goes from 1 to 9.

> 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64

Comment: Why is this tagged "C++" if you are asking about Delphi (Pascal) code?

Comment: I have removed the tag

Comment: Why do you care about this? It's undefined behaviour. Anything can happen. You are overwriting some other part of the stack. Maybe an error will come of that. Maybe not. Enable the range checking option and you will get a runtime error.

Comment: In C++ you have a pointer to the address of the first item of the array in the stack yes, but the same is with delphi. Given p: interger^ you can access the first item with @a (if a is the array)

Comment: But why is (p+1)^ not giving me the next item?

Comment: You cannot use (p+1)^ since it's not valid in Delphi. You can use Inc(p) and that will point to the next item of the array a.

Comment: Ah ok so Inc(p) will do the trick. But why Delphi cannot have that feature like C++?

Comment: Maybe because C++ != Delphi

Comment: @AlbertoMiola Shouldn't that be `C++ <> Delphi`? :)

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi If range-checking isn't enabled it's still possible to get an exception (access violation), but ***only if*** the invalid memory access is detected.

Comment: @CraigYoung haha yes probably it's better

Comment: @AlbertoMiola: "*You cannot use `(p+1)^` since it's not valid in Delphi*" - Yes, it is.  Delphi 2009 and later have a [`{$POINTERMATH ON}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Pointer_Math_(Delphi)) directive that enables such syntax and functionality.

Comment: Oh I didnt know thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why is this not raising the exception?

You likely don't have [Range Checks](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Range_checking) enabled.

> In the `{$R+}` state, all array and string-indexing expressions are verified as being within the defined bounds, and all assignments to scalar and subrange variables are checked to be within range. **If a range check fails, an `ERangeError` exception is raised (or the program is terminated if exception handling is not enabled).

Range Checks is OFF by default.  To enable it, you can add this directive to your code:

```pascal
{$RANGECHECKS ON}
```

Or you can enable it in the Project Options, under "Delphi Compiler | Compiling | Runtime Errors".

Comment: That was very easy, thank you. I put the compiler directive at the beginning and the exception raised as I expected!

Comment: Just remember that using `range checking` can significantly lower your code performance. So I only recommend using `range checking` in debug build or limiting it to just some parts of your code.

Comment: @SilverWarior: Yup, as the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Range_checking) says: "**Enabling range checking slows down your program and makes it somewhat larger.*"